# Upload file program

Tags: php, object-oriented

I'm working on an upload file program in PHP in OOP style. I need some feedback about code.

**index.php**

```
<?php 
require_once('./lib/upload.php');
?>

<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $fileupload = new upload();
    if(!$fileupload -> sizeck()){
        if($fileupload -> extens()){
            if($fileupload -> uploadfile()){
                echo 'Fisierul a fost uploadat';
            }
        }
    }   
}


?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form align="center" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
Select upload file: <input type="file" name="file" required="yes"  />
<input type="submit" value="Trimite" />
<p>
<p>
<p>
<br>If you want to view file and download <a href="./upload/"> click here </a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**lib/upload.php**

```
<?php
class upload{
    public $src = "upload/";
    public $tmp;
    public $filename;
    public $typefl;
    public $uploadfile;
    public $type = array("php", "css", "js", "html", "htm", ".php");

    function __construct(){
        $this -> filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $this -> tmp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $this -> uploadfile = $this -> src . basename($this -> filename);
    }
    public function sizeck(){
        if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 50000000){
            echo "Fisier prea mare";
            return true;
        }
    }
    public function extens(){
        $this -> typefl = pathinfo($this -> filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(in_array($this -> typefl, $this -> type)){
            echo "Fisier nepermis!!!";
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }


    public function uploadfile(){
        if(move_uploaded_file($this -> tmp, $this -> uploadfile)){
            return true;
        }
    }


}

?>
```

Comment: Just want to mention... Are you allowing uploads of `.php` files? Because that seems very dangerous. You might want to include some kind of MIUME checker. There are a couple ones out there using CURL to get the actual MIME type, but uploads are always dangerous.

Comment: No, i don't allow upload php.  "public $type = array("php", "css", "js", "html", "htm", ".php");"

Comment: Ah sorry, skim reading caught me on that one.

Comment: @cindeasorin It maybe an idea to change your type checker to contain allowed types rather than disallowed types. In this currency file I could upload an .exe file, .bat, .sh ect.... which you certainly do not want on your server.

Comment: Yes, i make this change, and i change more in script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not really object oriented, but here are some improvements:

- Use upper case names for classes (see CamelCase)
- Do not use an empty spaces between varibale `$object` and the method pointer ->, use e. g. `$object->method()`
- Do not use global variables like `$_FILES` in your classes. You should add a parameter which contains the file.
- Use human readable method names, like e. g. `verifyExtension()` instead of `extens()`
- Make your target uploading path on your server configurable (reusability)
- Do not use too many nested `if` conditions.
- Simpilfy your `if` nesting, e. g. combine your conditions and make configurable
- You can seperate your Validation and Upload, in two classes e. g. `FileValidation` and `FileUpload`
- You do not use your type checking attribute `$type` (type checking is missing)
- Do not use `echo` in your file uploading and validation classes.

These are only the most important improvements.